# Momentum a cotangent vector

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-mechanics

Apparently one identifies the configuration space in physics often with a manifold $M$. The tangent bundle $TM$ is then the space of all possible positions and velocities.

Furthermore, many sources seem to claim that $T^*M$ can be regarded as the phase space, where $(q,p) \in T^*M$ satisfies by definition that $p \in T_q^*M.$

Again by definition this means that $p:=\partial_2L$ takes velocities as arguments and is linear(!) in them. Unfortunately, I don't see from the definition of the momentum by the Lagrangian why this should be a linear functional. So something is confusing me here.

Comment: 'Apparently' and 'seem to claim' are pretty denigrating phrases. V.I. Arnold's famous book would be a good reference to check. An online source is http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/classical/, in particular http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/classical/cm05week06.pdf

Comment: @DavidRoberts: I think you're reading something into the question. It looks to me like the OP is just being cautious ...

Comment: OK, let me phrase my response like this: yes, the configuration space in physics _is_ a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold, and "in the Hamiltonian formulation of classical mechanics...this manifold's cotangent bundle describes the phase space of the system." (ibid). References there should help also (apologies for grumpy-seeming tone).

Comment: @DavidRoberts yes, that was my impression from reading the references: A phase space is a cotangent bundle, but then I thought that elements in the cotangent space need to be linear as it is a dual space and so I got confused. The reason is: I don't see why a momentum has to be linear in the velocities just by the definition via the Lagrangian or is this some additional physical input here?

Comment: Did you mean to write $p\in T^*_qM$ instead of $p\in T^*_pM$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Lagrangian is a function on the tangent bundle $L:TM\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Given a point $q\in M$ and a Lagrangian, we can define a function $L_q:T_qM\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ using the simple formula $L_q(v_q)=L(v_q)$, where $v_q\in T_qM$ is a tangent vector at $q\in M$. Notice that $L_q$ is a mapping between the vector spaces $T_qM$ and $\mathbb{R}$. We may therefore consider the Frechet derivative $DL_q:T_qM\rightarrow L(T_qM,\mathbb{R})$, where $L(T_qM,\mathbb{R})$ is the space of linear maps between $T_qM$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Notice that $DL_q$ is essentially the partial derivative of $L$ in the velocity direction.

Here is how the cotangent bundle comes in. The set $L(T_qM,\mathbb{R})$ is precisely the cotangent space at $q$, i.e. $L(T_qM,\mathbb{R})=T^*_qM$. Therefore the Frechet derivative of $L_q$ is a map of the form $DL_q:T_qM\rightarrow T^*_qM$. This observation can be used to construct a mapping of $TM$ into $T^*M$ given by $v_q\mapsto (DL_q)(v_q)\equiv p_q\in T^*_qM$, which is known as the Legendre transform.

Does this help?

Comment: Are you sure that's called the Legendre transform?  The Legendre transform relates the Lagragian $L$ to the Hamiltonian $H$.  (See, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation#Hamilton-Lagrange_mechanics )

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill I guess it depends on who you ask. In Abraham and Marsden on p. 219 they say "The transformation $\mathbf{F}L:TQ\rightarrow T^*Q$ thus maps the Lagrange equations into the Hamilton equations. In the literature  $\mathbf{F}L$ itself is sometimes called the Legendre transformation (e.g. Sternberg [1964]), while classically the name is usually reserved for the map that takes...[$L$ to $H$]." The Sternberg reference is this I think: http://www.amazon.com/Lectures-Differential-Geometry-Chelsea-Publishing/dp/0821813854.

Comment: I should also say that $\mathbf{F}L(v_q)=(DL_q)(v_q)$.

Comment: @JoshBurby, very interesting, I am starting to learn about this stuff, would you have any good reading recommendations?

Comment: @JoshBurby doesn't the Frechet derivative need the concept of norm?

Comment: @roi_saumon, while you do need some norm to define the limit used in the definition, in finite dimensions the choice of norm will not change the Frechet derivative. You might check this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183053/is-fr%C3%A9chet-derivative-independent-of-the-choice-of-norm

Answer (score 0):

$p$ is the differential of L with respect to the second variable ($\dot q$), so it represents a linear functional on the tangent space at $q, \dot q$), given by

$$ (u,v)\to \frac{d}{dt} L(q,\dot q+tv)|_{t=0}.$$

Comment: but the statement was that it is a linear functional on the tangent space at $q$?

Comment: More accurately it should be a linear functional on $T_{(q,\dot q)} TM$, which can be canonically identified as $T_qM$.

Comment: What is $u$? Also, I thought the momentum of a particle at $q\in M$ is a linear functional on the tangent space $T_qM$, as the question suggests, and not a linear functional on $T_{(q,\dot{q})}TM$. Note that the dimension of $T_{(q,\dot{q})}TM$ is twice the dimension of $M$, whereas the classical formula $p_i=\partial L/\partial q^i$ suggests that the momentum should have only $\text{dim}(M)$ components.

Comment: Yes, your expression is clearer. I should have discarded the $u$ and restricted $L$ to $T_qM$. It's not used anyway.